# JQuery Using Global Variable to link a Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss, global-variables

I'm working on a page that will show various RSS feeds, with tabbed navigation to show different RSS feeds. For the most part, I've got everything working and fine. However, at the top of the page, I have a header that says the name of the resource that is feeding the RSS.

I am using a global variable to store the link to the resource that is then used in a function to create the link. However, it's currently just causing all the headers to link to the same resource.

```
var link = null;
$.fn.rssFeedTopic = function(topicId) {
      switch(topicId) {
          case 'topHeadlines': 
               link = "https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us";
               $("#topHeadlines").rssfeed('https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&output=rss', "Google News ", {limit: 6, date:true});
               break;
          case 'topMDHeadlines':
               link = "http://wtop.com/region/local/maryland/";
               $("#topMDHeadlines").rssfeed('http://wtop.com/region/local/maryland/feed/', "WTOP - Maryland Stories ", {limit: 6, date:true});
               break;
          case 'topBusinessHeadlines':
               link = "https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&topic=b";
               $("#topBusinessHeadlines").rssfeed('https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&topic=b&output=rss', "Google News - Business ", {limit: 6, date:true});
               break;
          case 'topSportsHeadlines':
               link = "https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&topic=s";
               $("#topSportsHeadlines").rssfeed('https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&topic=s&output=rss', "Google News - Sports ", {limit: 6, date:true}); 
               break;
       }
};
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebbBliss/o9kcwLwy/) with the full code.

I'm still learning JQuery so I suspect I'm probably doing something wrong. Just let me know.

Comment: The code in the fiddle works fine as far as I can tell. When I click on different tabs I get different feeds.

Comment: The tabs work, the problem is when you click on the title below the tabs, the URLs the titles are linked with are always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the HTML code for the headlines is created asynchronously. You are iterating through the data for each tab, set the global variable “link” to the URL, then create each tab's HTML code, *but* the HTML code is created only after the JSON data has been loaded – by that time, your loop is already done iterating and the last value assigned to *link* in the loop, the sports page, is used for each tab.

You can fix this by getting rid of the global variable and passing your link URL as an additional option to your *rssFeed* jQuery plugin like this:

```
$("#topHeadlines").rssfeed(
    'https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&output=rss', 
    "Google News ",
    {
        limit: 6,
        date:true,
        link: "https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us"
    }
);
```

In your _callback function:

```
html += '<div class="rssHeader">' + 
        '<a href="' + options.link + '" ' +
        'title="' + news + '">' + news + '</a></div>';
```

Here's an updated version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/LtqLo7Ly/1/

Comment: Thanks so much! I seemed to have been trying to make it harder than it actually was haha. It works just how I need it to, now

Comment: Glad I could help you! 